# How [undefined, undefined, undefined] and new Array(3) are different in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose we have 3 arrays:

```
var arr1 = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
var arr2 = [, , ,];
var arr3 = new Array(3);
```

Are all of them identical in JavaScript?
If we wants to use `undefined` as default value for fixed size array, can we use them interchangeably?

Comment: @Pointy I've seen it right before your comment.. stupid me..

Comment: @MateiMihai it's a difference, but for many purposes it doesn't matter. Really in practice I always just use `[]` for an empty array. Relying on the array length seems like a really fragile design pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second two are the same (though the second one might cause issues on some browsers), but the first is different.

The first one

```
var arr1 = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
```

makes *explicit* assignments to the first three indexes in the array. Even though you're assigning `undefined`, the fact that indexes `0`, `1`, and `2` are targets of assignment operations means that those elements of the array will be treated as "real" by methods like `.reduce()`:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined].reduce(function(c) { return c + 1; }, 0);
// 3

[,,].reduce(function(c) { return c + 1; }, 0);
// 0
```

Many of the Array.prototype methods skip uninitialized array elements.